# Page stop responding while loading custom javascript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am new to GTM

1. I am running the following custom javascript in a variable.

```
function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
    let data = dataLayer.push({'event':'prefers-color-scheme','prefers-color-scheme':'dark'});
      return data;
    }
}
```

[image: Snap of step 1]

2. I have created a trigger, that trigger on DOM Ready, when the condition is set to 1, as 1 means true in JS.
   [image: Snap of step 2]
3. I have Created a tag of Google Universal Analytics which is tracking an event and trigging, what I send in 2nd step and in this step, I have given Event Category, Action and label a name.
   [image: Snap of step 3]
   I have also made a Data Layer Variable with version 2. `prefers-color-scheme`
   [image: Adding a data layer variable]

I have repeated same steps for Light and not supported, but the browser seems to get stuck and I have to kill the browser window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your issue that you can't view the data in the UI?

Comment: @bamdan I have explain my issue more as I was able to move forward

Comment: There seems to be no reason for the browser to get stuck running the above function. Could you share little more code. Maybe the cause is elsewhere

Comment: @Royson I wonder if this is the way to do it? This morning I tried to add {{}} around my category and set the Non-Interaction Hit to false. I am not sure why the issue as it freezes the whole website in the morning.

Comment: @MauriceNino what sort of info? I provided the steps in question which can be re-produced

Comment: @Nofel Could you please provide at least some more code like i. e. where you call your anonymous function, the DOM-ready event listener, and your HTML code where the scripts are embedded? Based on your sparse problem description, we unfortunately cannot really help you because **anything** could be the reason why the browser hangs up - recursive function call / infinite loop / too big response etc. etc.

Comment: Try creating a minimal example of code where the error still exists. And then add the FULL code here. Opening a bounty is not a "do work for me" button.

Comment: @SparkFountain I have posted screenshots now. When I create other function for "light", "not supported". I repeated the same steps so depending on preferences, it kicks in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created an endless loop of events by pushing to the dataLayer inside a custom javascript variable definition; a variable is analyzed whenever new data is pushed into the dataLayer.

Your `Color Theme` variable should just be:

```
function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)").matches) {        
      return 2;
    }
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {        
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then `prefers-color-scheme` could technically be a constant 'dark' with your test case, but more generally, it could be a lookup table on `Color Theme`:

```
Lookup on {{Color Theme}}
  2 no-preference
  1 dark
  0 light
```

or it could be an independent custom variable by returning the desired display names:

```
function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)").matches) {        
      return "no-preference";
    }
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {        
      return "dark";
    }
    return "light";
}
```

Allowing you to factor out the `Theme` variable(s) from your firing rule by restricting firing on `prefers-color-scheme` as desired and using it as the event tag's Action.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know how did I made a endless loop? In your first option it will return 1 which is meeting trigger criteria? But for example sake I gave one scenario as there r couple more like light, not supported etc, can I put them into one function or create each custom JavaScript for each (like I have it now) ? In ur second option ur returning word dark or light. Do I need to create variable names with Those name and in trigger pass those to be equal.

Comment: every dataLayer.push() runs every custom variable function(){} to have the results for any triggers etc and every run of this function is a datalayer push if you are in dark mode.. so anyone in dark mode is in an endless loop of evaluating this function and pushing again..

Comment: you can return a same value for many different cases (i.e. vendor equivalents in older browsers may all return 1) or many different values for many different cases within one custom variable, then use a negative firing rule like not 0 or not "default" (if you return strings for the identified type as in my last example) to fire the same tag for everything but some uninteresting default.. you can also use many variants of a customvar but they will be harder to combine into useful triggers and labels.

Comment: in my example of directly defining prefers-color-scheme as a custom var that returns your category strings, you can match on strings to restrict the trigger to prefers-color-scheme not "light" if you don't want those events but want dark and no-preference or whatever other names you give states. Theres no need for other variables unless you cant decide on permanent category names to the extent that you cant keep the strings referenced in triggers to block or fire and strings returned by the customvar in sync.

Comment: I might be a little lost. So how do I record the event? As `prefers-color-scheme` is Event Category, Action can be dark, light etc. In ur code I don't see any push into `dataLayer` or how do I record those events?

Comment: in your example tag+vars, your category is actually the value of `prefers-color-scheme` which is light or dark.. probably you want category to be hardcoded and action to be the variable instead of the other way around..

Comment: For this specific example, clearer integration would be adding an analytics custom dimension and on page views having [cdim#] {{prefers-color-scheme}} with the variable that returns strings.. But then there is no real need in triggers as tags are not fired dependent on the value of the variable.

Comment: Should I be [seeing](https://imgur.com/a/S7DvpXZ) this after changing the code as I changed according to your first example?

Comment: Yeah but you did: "you can also use many variants of a customvar but they will be harder to combine into useful triggers and labels."

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the 3rd option and hopefully make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Great, thanks. Although it is very new to me I would like to know where I can learn more about it and why my code was wrong

Comment: 3rd party docs like: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#4-custom-javascript seem to cover a bit and can hopefully put blogs about various patterns and the significant details into perspective.. mainly its a matter of practising refactoring among the possible ways of generalizing as well as from one test case up to them and building up experience with the problems and benefits of each..

Comment: I have a Event Action called undefined. How can i find what is undefined?

Comment: if you can find the event tag in the debugger then the name/values toggle should help you find the variable responsible and the variable view will show you all the variables values at the time of the event..